# Convert a Julian Date to Calendar date in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to convert a Julian Date into a Calendar Date but I can not find the correct PostgreSQL function to do so.

For Example: Given the Julian Date = 2456782, I would want something like 2014/05/04 back.

Thank You,

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 4):

Googling "postgres julian date" should bring you to the [Postgres date docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-datetime.html), which reveal that Julian dates are built into Postgres:

```
SELECT 'J2456782'::DATE;
    date    
------------
 2014-05-04
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `to_date` function:

```
to_date(2456782::text, 'J')
```

which will produce `2014-05-04`.

Comment: Do you know how to get the Julian date as an integer from a calendar date?

Comment: @mrts: `EXTRACT(julian FROM CURRENT_DATE)`